# Rearranging a csv file

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk, scripting

I have a file with contents similar to the below

```
Boy,Football
Boy,Football
Boy,Football
Boy,Squash
Boy,Tennis
Boy,Football
Girl,Tennis
Girl,Squash
Girl,Tennis
Girl,Tennis
Boy,Football
```

How can I use 'awk' or similar to rearrange this to the below:

```
     Football Tennis Squash
Boy  5        1      1
Girl 0        3      1
```

I'm not even sure if this is possible, but any help would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just loop normally:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="\t" '
          {names[$1]; sport[$2]; count[$1,$2]++}
          END{printf "%s", OFS;
              for (i in sport) 
                   printf "%s%s", i, OFS;
              print "";
              for (n in names) {
                   printf "%s%s", n, OFS
                   for (s in sport) 
                        printf "%s%s", count[n,s]?count[n,s]:0, OFS; print ""
                   }
               }' file
```

This keeps track of three arrays: `names[]` for the first column, `sport[]` for the second column and `count[name,sport]` to count the occurrences of every combination.

Then, it is a matter of looping through the results and printing them in a fancy way and making sure `0` is printed if the `count[a,b]` does not exist.

#### Test

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS="\t" '{names[$1]; sport[$2]; count[$1,$2]++} END{printf "%s", OFS; for (i in sport) printf "%s%s", i, OFS; print ""; for (n in names) {printf "%s%s", n, OFS; for (s in sport) printf "%s%s", count[n,s]?count[n,s]:0, OFS; print ""}}' a
    Squash  Tennis  Football    
Boy 1   1   5   
Girl    1   3   0
```

Format is a bit ugly, there are some trailing OFS.

To get rid of trailing OFS:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="\t" '{names[$1]; sport[$2]; count[$1,$2]++} END{printf "%s", OFS; for (i in sport) {cn++; printf "%s%s", i, (cn<length(sport)?OFS:ORS)} for (n in names) {cs=0; printf "%s%s", n, OFS; for (s in sport) {cs++; printf "%s%s", count[n,s]?count[n,s]:0, (cs<length(sport)?OFS:ORS)}}}' a
```

You can always pipe to `column -t` for a nice output.

Comment: Question for @Ed Morton: how can I loop through the data in `sport[]` array knowing when I am in the last item? If `sport['football']` and `sport['basketball']` are present, I cannot say `for (i in a)` and then check if `i == length(sport)`, uhms...

Comment: You can't without introducing some extra construct, either a counter as you have done or a separate array of indices. Your answer is fine and should stay as the accepted one but I posted an answer just to show how I'd really write the loops for this type of situation.

Answer (score 5):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ FS=","; OFS="\t" }
{
    genders[$1]
    sports[$2]
    count[$1,$2]++
}
END {
    printf ""
    for (sport in sports) {
        printf "%s%s", OFS, sport
    }
    print ""
    for (gender in genders) {
        printf "%s", gender
        for (sport in sports) {
            printf "%s%s", OFS, count[gender,sport]+0
        }
        print ""
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
        Squash  Tennis  Football
Boy     1       1       5
Girl    1       3       0
```

In general when you know the end point of the loop you put the OFS or ORS after each field:

```
for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
    printf "%s%s", $i, (i<n?OFS:ORS)
}
```

but if you don't then you put the OFS before the second and subsequent fields and print the ORS after the loop:

```
for (x in array) {
    printf "%s%s", (++i>1?OFS:""), array[x]
}
print ""
```

I do like the:

```
n = length(array)
for (x in array) {
    printf "%s%s", array[x], (++i<n?OFS:ORS)
}
```

idea to get the end of the loop too, but `length(array)` is gawk-specific.

Another approach to consider:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ FS=","; OFS="\t" }
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if (!seen[i,$i]++) {
            map[i,++num[i]] = $i
        }
    }
    count[$1,$2]++
}
END {
    for (i=0; i<=num[2]; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", map[2,i], (i<num[2]?OFS:ORS)
    }
    for (i=1; i<=num[1]; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", map[1,i], OFS
        for (j=1; j<=num[2]; j++) {
            printf "%s%s", count[map[1,i],map[2,j]]+0, (j<num[2]?OFS:ORS)
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
        Football        Squash  Tennis
Boy     5       1       1
Girl    0       1       3
```

That last will print the rows and columns in the order they were read. Not quite as obvious how it works though :-).

Comment: This is beautiful!!! Favoriting the question so I can come back to this answer often!!!