# How to keep track of printed items in a for loop?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, awk

I was [recently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30804324/1983854) dealing with a hash that I wanted to print in a nice manner.

To simplify, it is just n array with two fields `a['name']="me"`, `a['age']=77` and the data I want to print like `key1:value1,key2:value2,...` and end with a new line. That is:

```
name=me,age=77
```

Since it is not an array whose indices are autoincremented values, I do not know how to loop through them and know when I am processing the last one.

This is important because it allows to use a different separator on the case I am in the last one. Like this, a different character can be printed in this case (new line) instead of the one that is printed after the rest of the files (comma).

I ended up using a counter to compare to the length of the array:

```
awk 'BEGIN {a["name"]="me"; a["age"]=77;
            n = length(a);
            for (i in a) {
                count++; 
                printf "%s=%s%s", i, a[i], (count<n?",":ORS)
                }
            }'
```

This works well. However, is there any other better way to handle this? I don't like the fact of adding an extra `count++`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general when you know the end point of the loop you put the OFS or ORS after each field:

```
for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
    printf "%s%s", $i, (i<n?OFS:ORS)
}
```

but if you don't then you put the OFS before the second and subsequent fields and print the ORS after the loop:

```
for (idx in array) {
    printf "%s%s", (++i>1?OFS:""), array[idx]
}
print ""
```

I do like the:

```
n = length(array)
for (idx in array) {
    printf "%s%s", array[idx], (++i<n?OFS:ORS)
}
```

idea to get the end of the loop too, but `length(array)` is gawk-specific and the resulting code isn't any more concise or efficient than the 2nd loop above:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    OFS = ","
    array["name"] = "me"
    array["age"]  = 77 
    for (idx in array) {
        printf "%s%s=%s", (++i>1?OFS:""), array[idx], idx
    }
    print ""
}
```

vs

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    OFS = ","
    array["name"] = "me"
    array["age"]  = 77 
    n = length(array)      # or non-gawk: for (idx in array) n++
    for (idx in array) {
        printf "%s=%s%s", array[idx], idx, (++i<n?OFS:ORS)
    }
}
```

Comment: Now we have a canonical answer for this, thanks a lot for the huge amount of knowledge you are adding in [so]!